# Can I set the grid configuration before having any widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Suppose I have a frame which contains 5 widgets and uses the `grid` method to manage positions:

[image]

So far, so good. But what if I want now to make something like this (obtained using *bad* methods):

[image]

i.e. button `horizontal settings` spans 4 rows. If I were able to set grid configuration (say) in this manner: `grid(ncols = 1, nrows = 5)` and then I would do something like `button.columnconfigure(0,weight=4)` and `label.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)`.

How to solve this problem?

I will explain why this is not trivial question. It is because this two groups of widgets (on the 1st figure and on the 2nd) are in separate frames. So the first frame has 5 rows and the second has only 2. And widget will not be aligned:

[image]

EDIT:
This is piece of my code:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller

    labelFrame = tk.Frame(self)
    labelFrame.pack(fill='x', side="top")
    startLabel = tk.Label(labelFrame, 
                          text="Start page")
    startLabel.pack(pady=10)

    quitFrame = tk.Frame(self)
    quitFrame.pack(fill='x',side="bottom")
    quitButton = tk.Button(quitFrame, text="Quit",
                           command=quit,
                           bg="pink")
    quitButton.pack(pady=10)

    operateFrame = tk.Frame(self)
    operateFrame.pack()

    channelGroup = tk.Frame(operateFrame) 
    channelGroup.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = 'n')
    chLabel = tk.Label(channelGroup,
                       text="Channel group")
    chLabel.grid(pady=10)

    ch1Button = tk.Button(channelGroup, text="CH1 Settings",
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame("CH1"))
    ch1Button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    ch2Button = tk.Button(channelGroup, text="CH2 Settings",
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame("CH2"))
    ch2Button.grid(row=2, column=0)

    ch3Button = tk.Button(channelGroup, text="CH3 Settings",
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame("CH3"))
    ch3Button.grid(row=3, column=0)

    ch4Button = tk.Button(channelGroup, text="CH4 Settings",
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame("CH4"))
    ch4Button.grid(row=4, column=0)


    triggerGroup = tk.Frame(operateFrame)
    triggerGroup.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='n')
    trigLabel = tk.Label(triggerGroup,
                         text="Trigger group")
    trigLabel.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=10)
    trigButton = tk.Button(triggerGroup, text="Trigger Settings",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Trigger"))
    trigButton.grid()

    horizGroup = tk.Frame(operateFrame)
    horizGroup.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='n')
    horizLabel = tk.Label(horizGroup,
                          text="Horizontal group")
    horizLabel.grid(pady=10)
    horizButton = tk.Button(horizGroup,
                            text="Horizontal settings",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Horizontal"))
    horizButton.grid()
```

After that I get:

[image]

Comment: Each frame has it's own grid; the number of rows or columns in one does not affect the others. Why are you wanting to set the number columns and rows manually anyway? Just let the tkinter magic figure it out.

Comment: If I *let the tkinter magic figure it out* it will 5 rows in the 1st frame and only 2 in the 2nd. And widgets will not be aligned. I should mention this in the question. Edited.

Comment: Oh I see. Aligning frames should never have anything to do with the content. How are you laying out the Frames? If those are also in a grid, use `sticky='n'`.

Comment: If you provide us with [complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces this problem, I can show you how to fix it.

Comment: OK. Answering your 1st question: Yes, frames are in a grid. I used sticky as you said and it aligned labels. But I want buttons to fill the same space in *every* frame. Answering your 2nd question: I added the link to similar question on SE (where I am OP also).

Comment: Edited. Do not look at that link. I forgot that there was old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your example is not complete. To troubleshoot this I need to run it; I'm good but I'm not good enough to debug by eye. And you are asking me to write a bunch of boilerplate stuff. Post a COMPLETE code snippet; including imports and entry points.

To fix your problems you just need to tell the frame, the row, and the buttons to expand to all available vertical space with `sticky='ns'` and `rowconfigure(1, weight=1)`.

```
horizGroup = tk.Frame(operateFrame)
horizGroup.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns')
horizGroup.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
horizLabel = tk.Label(horizGroup,
                      text="Horizontal group")
horizLabel.grid(pady=10)
horizButton = tk.Button(horizGroup,
                        text="Horizontal settings",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Horizontal"))
horizButton.grid(sticky='ns')
```

Comment: It seems like you are not so bad to debug by eye. It works. Thank you so much.

Comment: I didn't debug by eye. I wrote 10 lines of code in order to get yours to run and was kinda grumpy about it.